# Install msi in the same path where msi is located

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm building a msi installer using wixtool. I'm able to install that msi in any location, by browsing the directory.

I'm trying to simplify the installation steps. What I need is I want to install the msi installer in the same path where the installer exists.

For example if I have my msi installer in D:\test directory, then it should install the same in D:\test directory without asking for the path to install.

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Installer sets the **OriginalDatabase** property to the path of the installation database used to launch the installation. If the installation is launched from a command line, the value depends on whether the recache package option (the -v flag) is present in the REINSTALLMODE property.

So, you can set the TARGETDIR to the value of the **OriginalDatabase** property